# Does Chromecast single video stream restriction apply to Audio objects?

Tags: google-cast

The Receiver application guidelines state that "Chromecast devices only support 1 concurrent media stream for playback" then goes on to discuss it only in terms of video. I find that just creating a single Audio object like this...

```
new Audio("/sound/beep1.mp3");
```

...will prevent any subsequent video from playing. Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chromecast only supports one active media element at a time, so if you have an Audio element/object, then you cannot have another Video element/object.